# RESTful for non resource oriented webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I'm all for REST webservices and my company has a policy in place to prefer REST over SOAP.

However, I need to expose a webservice that does not fit into the resource paradigm. It is essentially a calculation, where I need to send a large number of parameters (about 20 fields) and retrieve a number.

I thought about using HTTP POST and send a JSON object in the request body. Problem here is,  my webservice supports SOAP-WS and REST and this approach won't fall in any of these categories.

My question is, what are the options here ? Can I make this fit into a RESTful WS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention, REST makes sense when you're exposing [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on resources. Usually these resources are persisted in some database or storage mechanism.

In your case I guess there is no storage or resources (you provide a bunch of numbers and get a result back, nothing gets stored, is that true?). So you won't be able to really call such a WS as "RESTful".

That being said REST is more of a "philosophy". You can take the pieces you like and use them. Your idea of implementing a POST, taking in a JSON structure with your input and returning a JSON with the result sounds good. You can also POST "[application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)" content (a regular form submit and return the result as "text/plain" if that makes sense.

The idea is to build a WS that is simple to understand and easy to operate. The exact opposite of SOAP-WS. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why that couldn't be RESTful. Consider a particular calculation run to be a resource with its own identity (`/calculation/ID123`); you can then do a POST to `/calculation` to make a new one, GET/PUT on `/calculation/ID123/paramA` to work with a particular parameter, and GET on `/calculation/ID123/result` to retrieve the results of the calculation (or a description that says the calculation results are not available for some reason). Of course, GET on `/calculation` would be a retrieve of the list of saved calculations that you're allowed to see, GET on `/calculation/ID123` would retrieve a description of the sub-resources outlined above (plus whatever other info you want to provide), and purging a particular calculation is a DELETE.

There's nothing wrong with having lots of sub-resources and highly transient resources. The important thing to remember is that the client shouldn't ever be minting URLs. (I don't know whether content negotiation is so useful in this situation; that really depends on the particular calculation I suppose.)

Comment: IMHO That seems a little overkill. I believe the natural essence of the problem here is *function* as in `f(x)= ...` and this, although could be forced into, is not really a resource.